# Trying to unzip file

Tags: macos, terminal, finder

When trying to unzip a file, I ghet the following error:

```
Archive:  file.zip
skipping: file.bla            need PK compat. v4.5 (can do v2.1)
```

Can any one help?

Comment: Try `7z x file.zip` [install info](http://p7zip.sourceforge.net/), I am pretty sure that error is related to password protected zips, which the built in doesn't really support.

Answer (score 110, accepted):

Try to unzip it with `p7zip`.

You can install it via [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/) or [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) with these commands, respectively:

```
sudo port install p7zip

brew install p7zip
```

Then, to unzip it, use:

```
7za x file.zip
```

Comment: This works. I am just curious: does the `need PK compat. v4.5 (can do v2.1)` message mean that Info-ZIP (i.e. the standard `unzip`) can't read files in a newer format defined by PKWARE, or that this is in fact not a .zip file, but rather a 7z file?

Comment: @avernet then why Windows can do it and macOS not? Is macOS that bad?

Comment: I did use on macOS only `brew install p7zip` and `7za x file.zip` - all is working

Comment: this helped me too, mine was `need PK compat. v5.1 (can do v4.5)` just for google index. I also used brew.

Answer (score 2):

If you're emotionally attached to using the `unzip` command; this also works:

```
$ brew tap homebrew/dupes
$ brew install unzip
$ brew link unzip --force

# Warning: unzip is keg-only and must be linked with --force
# Note that doing so can interfere with building software.
```

Comment: as of 2021  "Error: homebrew/dupes was deprecated. This tap is now empty and all its contents were either deleted or migrated."

Answer (score 0):

If you're on an older Mac, XCode won't install without the latest OS. I just figured out that it works fine without Xcode or Homebrew, but you have to be comfortable running some terminal commands.

You can download 7za from [SourceForge](http://p7zip.sourceforge.net/). It will show up as a 7za file with a terminal exec icon. Then copy it to /usr/local/bin and `chmod +x /usr/local/bin/7za` (I had to create the bin folder). Then type 7za x path/to/your/file.zip and it should work.

```
$ sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/bin
$ sudo cp /Volumes/p7zip/7za /usr/local/bin
$ sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/7za
$ 7za x path/to/your/file.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

That file was zipped under Windows/Linux using 7zip and you are trying to unzip it under MacOS.

Download [The Unarchiver](https://theunarchiver.com/) from the App Store and use it to unzip it.